# How to change JAVA_HOME of a self-hosted agent in ADO only, without actually changing the JAVA_HOME env in the the actual server hosting the agent

Tags: java, azure-devops, sonarqube, java-11, java-home

I have both Java8 and Java 11 on the server that hosts the agent. All my programs on the server need Java8 to execute, but the agent that runs sonarqube requires Java11.
I cannot change JAVA_HOME in my server, but the sonarqube execution always fails with
`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`.
Because it picks up Java8 for run analysis purpose.
Is there any way to change the JavaHome variable in azure devops for Sonarqube scanner

I have tried setting different Task version and JDK version in Run analysis tasks, but its of no help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Need java 8**? Except for very tricky things, Java 11 can run Java 8 code. Looking at your error, Sonar is running in Java 8, run everything in Java 11.